# Deleting 3 columns from whole <body>

Tags: html

My website has 3 separate columns which I can't get rid of. I deleted the code but it's still showing up. Can you please help?

Comment: What have you tried where is your code ?

Comment: Hello, please share some code :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).